# My jQuery completely breaks in IE7

Tags: jquery, validation, internet-explorer-7

Pretty much what topic says. I've been trying for quite some time now to rewrite stuff, checking the brackets, semicolons, parentheses and all that jazz. Still comepletely breaks in IE7.

I'm not saying I'm some sort of guru when it comes to these things, I can do basic stuff but 90% of the times I pretty much copy/paste plugin stuff. If anyone could take a look at it I'd be most grateful.

View it here:
http://snippi.com/s/9h7pf0b

Comment: This is not a "plz fix my code"-site. What have you tried?

Comment: SO is for specific programming questions, not generically broad _"fix my site"_ type questions.  Also, how are we supposed to test your site in IE 7 without a link to the site in question?

Comment: Johan & Sparky672: I never asked for someone to completely make it work, I merely asked if someone could take a look and what I was doing wrong. And if you continued to read you would see "[...] rewrite stuff, checking the brackets, semicolons, parentheses [...]".

Sparky: I would love to give you a live link, but it is confidential as of now, even thought I hardly think anyone outside of Sweden would ever visit it. So I am sorry for that.

Marangs: I'd love to, but there are still people stuck with it for various reasons, and they should not be ignored if they can't do something about it.

Comment: There are valid reasons we made those comments.  SO is not only here for you; these questions remain here to help others in the future.  So in order to best help others, questions and answers should be very specific and they should be fully "self-contained".  Yours is neither.  [See the FAQ for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE7 doesn't like `,` before `}` so:

```
    directionalNav  : false,
```

should become

```
    directionalNav  : false
```

same thing for all the other occurrences

Comment: IE8 also doesn't like trailing ',' in an object.

Comment: Thank you. That sure cleared some stuff up, going to note that for future projects. Still a few kinks to be worked out but I should be able to make the rest from there.

Comment: Google "trailing comma of death".